# Removing "noise" from edges of sid Imagery File using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, mrsid

I have several .sid imagery files of the state of Oregon that I want to display in my map sheets. 
The imagery is surrounded by black pixels. I was able to remove the black pixels by checking the "Display Background Values: (R, G, B)" and setting it to 0, 0, 0.
But there is still (what I'm describing) as "noise" left around the pixels that I cannot get rid of (see image below).
[image]
I tried clipping the raster and that did not work.
I searched in several forums and couldn't find a resolution.
Any Ideas/suggestions?

Comment: Why did clipping not work as that is what everyone else would do? What was your error message when clipping failed?

Comment: Have you tried searching [gis se](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=Clip+raster+arcmap)?

Comment: Some updates: the noise that appears to be black is actually pixels that are not RGB = 0,0,0. The have different values, such as 0,1,0 or 0,2,1 and so on. So technically they are not black but some other shades of black/gray. Nevertheless, I need to get rid of them some how.
In addition, let me rephrase the clipping. It does work, but the file size the the area I'm looking at are so large, the clipping process creates an enormous file size and takes too much time. I rather just use my original images and remove the "noise" from the edges.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to remove that "noise" by using the "Clip (Data Management)" tool.

Comment: So you are clipping it without creating this enormous file size you mentioned?

Comment: Yes Hornbydd, I was able to clipp the MrSid file and convert it into a TIFF file while keeping the file size relatively small. Thanks for your help!